# Is there a brand of bicycle named BUILD

Tags: identify-this-bike, electric-bike

A bicycle had passed my home today rather quickly. The frame had the word 'Build' painted on it. I am assuming it is an electric bicycle, but I would like to know more about this bike. Is 'Build' the company name? Is it made in Canada? Is it actually electric?

It would perhaps be a potential purchase of mine.

Comment: Not sure anyone might be able to give you an answer to any off these questions.  I myself have never heard of a bike brand Build and not an easy google search.  Is it Canadian?, who knows.  Is it electric?  couldn't even guess

Comment: That's a hard word to google in relation to bikes, but consider it could be something similar like **BULLET** or **WILIER**  (whose logo is cursive and could read as build)

Comment: Your better option might be to go shopping at a local bike shop that specialises in electric, and see if they have suggestions.

Comment: Also consider that anyone can slap any word on a bike.  You could call your bike a BUILD or a poorsche or a freeari or anything that can be cut by a decal-maker.

Answer (score -2):

The closest I have found to a bike brand of this name is a web-page that looks like a test page:

[image]

but it is actually the [homepage of *Changzhou Brand Outdoor Co., Ltd*](https://www.czbrandoutdoor.com/), a company that is selling ebikes.

Kind of funny the sentence "our products can match CCC, EN1888 testing". Sure, they can match, on which side of the threshold values? I would let someone else be the beta-tester (or alpha-) of their products ...

Comment: I used that big search enginge that once was useful to find reviews on geocities, and now it finds almost only commercial results, with the key  *""build brand" ebike* and I still had to scroll quite down in the results, like results nr. 15 or 16.
Picking that name = great SEO skills :D

Comment: How does this answer the question? I don't see any bikes on that page that have BUILD on them? Unless OP misread the word BRAND of course.

Comment: ups, I comüpletely misread the question